# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe' on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, caffe, pycaffe, deep-dream

I wanted to make a deepdream video using this script: https://github.com/graphific/DeepDreamVideo. I had to make few changes to it but now I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\deepdream-master\2_dreaming_time.py", line 20, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\deepdream-master\caffe\python\caffe\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\deepdream-master\caffe\python\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'
```

I've installed caffe by `pip install caffe-ssd-x86` but it doesn't resolve this problem. I'm using windows 10 and Python 3.8

The code I'm using now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
__author__ = 'graphific'

import argparse
import os, os.path
import errno
import sys
import time
import subprocess
from random import randint



from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd
import PIL.Image
from google.protobuf import text_format

sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\deepdream-master\caffe\python')
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

def extractVideo(inputdir, outputdir):
    print(subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -i ' + inputdir + ' -f image2 ' + outputdir + '/%08d.png', shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())

def showarray(a, fmt='jpeg'):
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
    f = StringIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))

def showarrayHQ(a, fmt='png'):
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
    f = StringIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))

# a couple of utility functions for converting to and from Caffe's input image layout
def preprocess(net, img):
    #print np.float32(img).shape
    return np.float32(np.rollaxis(img, 2)[::-1]) - net.transformer.mean['data']
def deprocess(net, img):
    return np.dstack((img + net.transformer.mean['data'])[::-1])

def objective_L2(dst):
    dst.diff[:] = dst.data

#objective for guided dreaming
def objective_guide(dst,guide_features):
    x = dst.data[0].copy()
    y = guide_features
    ch = x.shape[0]
    x = x.reshape(ch,-1)
    y = y.reshape(ch,-1)
    A = x.T.dot(y) # compute the matrix of dot-products with guide features
    dst.diff[0].reshape(ch,-1)[:] = y[:,A.argmax(1)] # select ones that match best

#from https://github.com/jrosebr1/bat-country/blob/master/batcountry/batcountry.py
def prepare_guide(net, image, end="inception_4c/output", maxW=224, maxH=224):
        # grab dimensions of input image
        (w, h) = image.size

        # GoogLeNet was trained on images with maximum width and heights
        # of 224 pixels -- if either dimension is larger than 224 pixels,
        # then we'll need to do some resizing
        if h > maxH or w > maxW:
            # resize based on width
            if w > h:
                r = maxW / float(w)

            # resize based on height
            else:
                r = maxH / float(h)

            # resize the image
            (nW, nH) = (int(r * w), int(r * h))
            image = np.float32(image.resize((nW, nH), PIL.Image.BILINEAR))

        (src, dst) = (net.blobs["data"], net.blobs[end])
        src.reshape(1, 3, nH, nW)
        src.data[0] = preprocess(net, image)
        net.forward(end=end)
        guide_features = dst.data[0].copy()

        return guide_features

# -------
# Make dreams
# -------
def make_step(net, step_size=1.5, end='inception_4c/output', jitter=32, clip=True):
    '''Basic gradient ascent step.'''

    src = net.blobs['data'] # input image is stored in Net's 'data' blob
    dst = net.blobs[end]

    ox, oy = np.random.randint(-jitter, jitter + 1, 2)
    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], ox, -1), oy, -2) # apply jitter shift

    net.forward(end=end)
    dst.diff[:] = dst.data  # specify the optimization objective
    net.backward(start=end)
    g = src.diff[0]
    # apply normalized ascent step to the input image
    src.data[:] += step_size / np.abs(g).mean() * g

    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], -ox, -1), -oy, -2) # unshift image

    if clip:
        bias = net.transformer.mean['data']
        src.data[:] = np.clip(src.data, -bias, 255-bias)

def deepdream(net, base_img, image_type, iter_n=10, octave_n=4, octave_scale=1.4, end='inception_4c/output', verbose = 1, clip=True, **step_params):

    # prepare base images for all octaves
    octaves = [preprocess(net, base_img)]
    for i in range(octave_n - 1):
        octaves.append(nd.zoom(octaves[-1], (1, 1.0 / octave_scale, 1.0 / octave_scale), order=1))

    src = net.blobs['data']
    detail = np.zeros_like(octaves[-1]) # allocate image for network-produced details
    for octave, octave_base in enumerate(octaves[::-1]):
        h, w = octave_base.shape[-2:]
        if octave > 0:
            # upscale details from the previous octave
            h1, w1 = detail.shape[-2:]
            detail = nd.zoom(detail, (1, 1.0 * h / h1, 1.0 * w / w1), order=1)

        src.reshape(1,3,h,w) # resize the network's input image size
        src.data[0] = octave_base+detail
        for i in range(iter_n):
            make_step(net, end=end, clip=clip, **step_params)

            # visualization
            vis = deprocess(net, src.data[0])
            if not clip: # adjust image contrast if clipping is disabled
                vis = vis * (255.0 / np.percentile(vis, 99.98))
            if verbose == 3:
                if image_type == "png":
                    showarrayHQ(vis)
                elif image_type == "jpg":
                    showarray(vis)
                print (octave, i, end, vis.shape)
                clear_output(wait=True)
            elif verbose == 2:
                print (octave, i, end, vis.shape)

        # extract details produced on the current octave
        detail = src.data[0]-octave_base
    # returning the resulting image
    return deprocess(net, src.data[0])

# --------------
# Guided Dreaming
# --------------
def make_step_guided(net, step_size=1.5, end='inception_4c/output',
              jitter=32, clip=True, objective_fn=objective_guide, **objective_params):
    '''Basic gradient ascent step.'''

    #if objective_fn is None:
    #    objective_fn = objective_L2

    src = net.blobs['data'] # input image is stored in Net's 'data' blob
    dst = net.blobs[end]

    ox, oy = np.random.randint(-jitter, jitter+1, 2)
    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], ox, -1), oy, -2) # apply jitter shift

    net.forward(end=end)
    objective_fn(dst, **objective_params)  # specify the optimization objective
    net.backward(start=end)
    g = src.diff[0]
    # apply normalized ascent step to the input image
    src.data[:] += step_size/np.abs(g).mean() * g

    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], -ox, -1), -oy, -2) # unshift image

    if clip:
        bias = net.transformer.mean['data']
        src.data[:] = np.clip(src.data, -bias, 255-bias)

def deepdream_guided(net, base_img, image_type, iter_n=10, octave_n=4, octave_scale=1.4, end='inception_4c/output', clip=True, verbose=1, objective_fn=objective_guide, **step_params):

    #if objective_fn is None:
    #    objective_fn = objective_L2

    # prepare base images for all octaves
    octaves = [preprocess(net, base_img)]
    for i in range(octave_n-1):
        octaves.append(nd.zoom(octaves[-1], (1, 1.0/octave_scale,1.0/octave_scale), order=1))

    src = net.blobs['data']
    detail = np.zeros_like(octaves[-1]) # allocate image for network-produced details
    for octave, octave_base in enumerate(octaves[::-1]):
        h, w = octave_base.shape[-2:]
        if octave > 0:
            # upscale details from the previous octave
            h1, w1 = detail.shape[-2:]
            detail = nd.zoom(detail, (1, 1.0*h/h1,1.0*w/w1), order=1)

        src.reshape(1,3,h,w) # resize the network's input image size
        src.data[0] = octave_base+detail
        for i in range(iter_n):
            make_step_guided(net, end=end, clip=clip, objective_fn=objective_fn, **step_params)

            # visualization
            vis = deprocess(net, src.data[0])
            if not clip: # adjust image contrast if clipping is disabled
                vis = vis*(255.0/np.percentile(vis, 99.98))
            if verbose == 3:
                if image_type == "png":
                    showarrayHQ(vis)
                elif image_type == "jpg":
                    showarray(vis)
                print(octave, i, end, vis.shape)
                clear_output(wait=True)
            elif verbose == 2:
                print(octave, i, end, vis.shape)

        # extract details produced on the current octave
        detail = src.data[0]-octave_base
    # returning the resulting image
    return deprocess(net, src.data[0])

def resizePicture(image,width):
    img = PIL.Image.open(image)
    basewidth = width
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    return img.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

def morphPicture(filename1,filename2,blend,width):
    img1 = PIL.Image.open(filename1)
    img2 = PIL.Image.open(filename2)
    if width != 0:
        img2 = resizePicture(filename2,width)
    return PIL.Image.blend(img1, img2, blend)

def make_sure_path_exists(path):
    '''
    make sure input and output directory exist, if not create them.
    If another error (permission denied) throw an error.
    '''
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

layersloop = ['inception_4c/output', 'inception_4d/output',
              'inception_4e/output', 'inception_5a/output',
              'inception_5b/output', 'inception_5a/output',
              'inception_4e/output', 'inception_4d/output',
              'inception_4c/output']

def main(input, output, image_type, gpu, model_path, model_name, preview, octaves, octave_scale, iterations, jitter, zoom, stepsize, blend, layers, guide_image, start_frame, end_frame, verbose):
    make_sure_path_exists(input)
    make_sure_path_exists(output)

     # let max nr of frames
    nrframes =len([name for name in os.listdir(input) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(input, name))])
    if nrframes == 0:
        print("no frames to process found")
        sys.exit(0)

    if preview is None: preview = 0
    if octaves is None: octaves = 4
    if octave_scale is None: octave_scale = 1.5
    if iterations is None: iterations = 5
    if jitter is None: jitter = 32
    if zoom is None: zoom = 1
    if stepsize is None: stepsize = 1.5
    if blend is None: blend = 0.5 #can be nr (constant), random, or loop
    if verbose is None: verbose = 1
    if layers is None: layers = 'customloop' #['inception_4c/output']
    if start_frame is None:
        frame_i = 1
    else:
        frame_i = int(start_frame)
    if not end_frame is None:
        nrframes = int(end_frame)+1
    else:
        nrframes = nrframes+1

    #Load DNN
    net_fn   = model_path + 'deploy.prototxt'
    param_fn = model_path + model_name #'bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel'

    if gpu is None:
        print("SHITTTTTTTTTTTTTT You're running CPU man =D")
    else:
        caffe.set_mode_gpu()
        caffe.set_device(int(args.gpu))
        print(("GPU mode [device id: %s]" % args.gpu))
        print("using GPU, but you'd still better make a cup of coffee")

    # Patching model to be able to compute gradients.
    # Note that you can also manually add "force_backward: true" line to "deploy.prototxt".
    model = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
    text_format.Merge(open(net_fn).read(), model)
    model.force_backward = True
    open('tmp.prototxt', 'w').write(str(model))

    net = caffe.Classifier('tmp.prototxt', param_fn,
                           mean = np.float32([104.0, 116.0, 122.0]), # ImageNet mean, training set dependent
                           channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB

    if verbose == 3:
        from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display
        print("display turned on")
    frame = np.float32(PIL.Image.open(input + '/%08d.%s' % (frame_i, image_type) ))
    if preview != 0:
        frame = np.float32(resizePicture(input + '/%08d.%s' % (frame_i, image_type), preview))

    now = time.time()
    totaltime = 0
    
    if blend == 'loop':
        blend_forward = True
        blend_at = 0.4
        blend_step = 0.1

    for i in range(frame_i, nrframes):
        print(('Processing frame #{}').format(frame_i))

        #Choosing Layer
        if layers == 'customloop': #loop over layers as set in layersloop array
            endparam = layersloop[frame_i % len(layersloop)]
        else: #loop through layers one at a time until this specific layer
            endparam = layers[frame_i % len(layers)]

        #Choosing between normal dreaming, and guided dreaming
        if guide_image is None:
            frame = deepdream(net, frame, image_type=image_type, verbose=verbose, iter_n = iterations, step_size = stepsize, octave_n = octaves, octave_scale = octave_scale, jitter=jitter, end = endparam)
        else:
            guide = np.float32(PIL.Image.open(guide_image))
            print('Setting up Guide with selected image')
            guide_features = prepare_guide(net,PIL.Image.open(guide_image), end=endparam)

            frame = deepdream_guided(net, frame, image_type=image_type, verbose=verbose, iter_n = iterations, step_size = stepsize, octave_n = octaves, octave_scale = octave_scale, jitter=jitter, end = endparam, objective_fn=objective_guide, guide_features=guide_features,)

        saveframe = output + "/%08d.%s" % (frame_i, image_type)

        later = time.time()
        difference = int(later - now)
        totaltime += difference
        avgtime = (totaltime / i)
        # Stats (stolen + adapted from Samim: https://github.com/samim23/DeepDreamAnim/blob/master/dreamer.py)
        print('***************************************')
        print('Saving Image As: ' + saveframe)
        print('Frame ' + str(i) + ' of ' + str(nrframes-1))
        print('Frame Time: ' + str(difference) + 's')
        timeleft = avgtime * ((nrframes-1) - frame_i)        
        m, s = divmod(timeleft, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        print('Estimated Total Time Remaining: ' + str(timeleft) + 's (' + "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s) + ')')
        print('***************************************')

        PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(frame)).save(saveframe)
        newframe = input + "/%08d.%s" % (frame_i,image_type)

        if blend == 0:
            newimg = PIL.Image.open(newframe)
            if preview != 0:
                newimg = resizePicture(newframe,preview)
            frame = newimg
        else:
       
            if blend == 'random':
                blendval=randint(5,10)/10.
            elif blend == 'loop':
                if blend_at > 1 - blend_step: blend_forward = False
                elif blend_at <= 0.5: blend_forward = True
                if blend_forward: blend_at += blend_step
                else: blend_at -= blend_step
                blendval = blend_at
            else: blendval = float(blend)
            frame = morphPicture(saveframe,newframe,blendval,preview)

        frame = np.float32(frame)

        now = time.time()
        frame_i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dreaming in videos.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i','--input',
        help='Input directory where extracted frames are stored',
        required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-o','--output',
        help='Output directory where processed frames are to be stored',
        required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-it','--image_type',
        help='Specify whether jpg or png ',
        required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--gpu",
        default= None,
        help="Switch for gpu computation."
    ) #int can chose index of gpu, if there are multiple gpu's to chose from
    parser.add_argument(
        '-t', '--model_path',
        dest='model_path',
        default='../caffe/models/bvlc_googlenet/',
        help='Model directory to use')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-m', '--model_name',
        dest='model_name',
        default='bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel',
        help='Caffe Model name to use')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-p','--preview',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help='Preview image width. Default: 0')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-oct','--octaves',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help='Octaves. Default: 4')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-octs','--octavescale',
        type=float,
        required=False,
        help='Octave Scale. Default: 1.4',)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-itr','--iterations',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help='Iterations. Default: 10')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-j','--jitter',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help='Jitter. Default: 32')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-z','--zoom',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help='Zoom in Amount. Default: 1')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-s','--stepsize',
        type=float,
        required=False,
        help='Step Size. Default: 1.5')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-b','--blend',
        type=str,
        required=False,
        help='Blend Amount. Default: "0.5" (constant), or "loop" (0.5-1.0), or "random"')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-l','--layers',
        nargs="+",
        type=str,
        required=False,
        help='Array of Layers to loop through. Default: [customloop] \
        - or choose ie [inception_4c/output] for that single layer')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-v', '--verbose',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help="verbosity [0-3]")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-gi', '--guide_image',
        required=False,
        help="path to guide image")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-sf', '--start_frame',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help="starting frame nr")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-ef', '--end_frame',
        type=int,
        required=False,
        help="end frame nr")
    parser.add_argument(
    '-e', '--extract',
    type=int,
    required=False,
    help="Extract frames from video")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.model_path[-1] == '/':
        args.model_path = args.model_path + '/'

    if not os.path.exists(args.model_path):
        print("Model directory not found")
        print("Please set the model_path to a correct caffe model directory")
        sys.exit(0)

    model = os.path.join(args.model_path, args.model_name)

    if not os.path.exists(model):
        print("Model not found")
        print("Please set the model_name to a correct caffe model")
        print("or download one with ./caffe_dir/scripts/download_model_binary.py caffe_dir/models/bvlc_googlenet")
        sys.exit(0)
        
    if args.extract == 1:
        extractVideo(args.input, args.output)

    else:
        main(args.input, args.output, args.image_type, args.gpu, args.model_path, args.model_name, args.preview, args.octaves, args.octavescale, args.iterations, args.jitter, args.zoom, args.stepsize, args.blend, args.layers, args.guide_image, args.start_frame, args.end_frame, args.verbose)
```

Do you have any solutions on this problem? I was searching on Google for answers but couldn't find any, thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Install caffe from [source](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I install from the source but get this same problem.
Still no idea what happen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, while importing Caffe after installing Caffe in windows with GPU, could fix it by copying `<CAFFE installation>/caffe/python/caffe/` to `<Python Directory>/Lib/site-packages`

Hope this will help, all the best..!